# Unprotect excel file before when it tries to open

Tags: excel, vba

I have protected my excel files with a vba code. Now I need a code that unprotect the files i have already protected. For example:

My protected file has password: 1234

When i try to open the file a pop up asks for the password (like when you protect the excel on file level)

I want to unprotect it automatically and i don't know how to do it.

Please see below the code to protect the files.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim path As String
Dim masterfile As Workbook

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set masterfile = ThisWorkbook
'Set masterfile = Workbooks("I:\protect workbooks.xlsm")

For i = 3 To 4

    masterfile.Activate
    path = Worksheets("Files").Range("B" & i)
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=path
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path, Password:="AT2020", WriteRespassword:="AT2020"
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

Next i

MsgBox "The files are now protected"

End Sub
```

Any suggestions how to unprotect?

Comment: `Workbooks.Open Filename:=path, Password:="your_password"` See more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open)

Comment: Hello  Vitaliy Prushak, thank you for your answer. I have already done this. By doing that the excel file open. What i want to do is to open it with that command and leave the file unprotected. Any ideas?

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect Password:="your_password"` Also, I strongly recommend you to look through [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.unprotect) before posting a question. There is an object tree on the left, so you can find any object and read what properties and methods the object has, and how it works.